# PHP - Issue with the printed result

Tags: php

i have this exercise from class, that we need to make script with a function that uses a given string as parameter in lowercase and i have to return that same string in uppercase, i already made that, but when it comes to the printing, it prints the letters in alphabetical order, and i cant figure out whats wrong, here's the code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Ejercicio 10</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <center><h1>Ejercicio 10 (Función 1)</h1></center>

 <h1>
 <center>

<form action="ejercicio10.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="frase" name="frase" placeholders="Introduzca una frase para transformar a mayusculas"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

<?php

$frase = $_POST['frase'];

function mayusculas($frase) {

$longitud = strlen($frase);
$minusculas = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","w","x","y","z"," ");
$mayusculas = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"," ");
$numeroLetras = count($minusculas);

for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud + 1; $i++) {

 for ($j=0; $j < $numeroLetras ; $j++) {

  $resultado = strrpos($frase, $minusculas[$j], $i);

    if($resultado !== FALSE){

    print($mayusculas[$j]);
    }
   }

   return null;

  }

}

  print(mayusculas($frase));

 ?>

</center>
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use the built in php function ? is it necessary to code your own function ?

Comment: Why not use `strtoupper()`?

Comment: Yes it is, i know that I can do that with the strtoupper function, but the professor wants us to learn how to do this kind of things

Comment: Your instructions say that you're supposed to *return* the string. You're not returning anything, you're printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright for the sake of the exercise, here is what is happening.

You are using two loops. The outer loop iterates as many times as the length of the string, and the inner loop iterates through each letter A through Z.

Here is the correct working version, and then I will explain:

```
function mayusculas($frase) {

    $longitud = strlen($frase);
    $minusculas = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","w","x","y","z"," ");
    $mayusculas = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"," ");
    $numeroLetras = count($minusculas);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud + 1; $i++) {

        for ($j=0; $j < $numeroLetras ; $j++) {

            $resultado = strpos($frase, $minusculas[$j], $i);

            if($resultado == $i && $resultado !== false) {
                print($mayusculas[$j]);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Your for loops are correct, it's what you are doing inside them that is not. The following needed to happen:

- First, you should use strpos instead of strrpos. We are going through the letters in the word forward, not backwards.
- When we check for `false` in the result, we also need to check that the position it found the letter is the position of the letter we are looking for (i.e. from the outer loop)
- Once we find a matching letter at the correct position, you can output it. And then we want to STOP the inner loop iteration since we are done with that loop.
- Finally, after the first iteration of the outer loop, you were returning `null`, which is incorrect. That stops the outer loop from moving on to the second letter. We need to let the looping run its course.

A final note, this is no where close to the best way to do this. I'm only highlighting for learning sake.

Comment: Ok, i tested it and its perfect, thanks for your help, time and for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Using this loop `for ($j=0; $j < $numeroLetras ; $j++) {` and doing this `$resultado = strrpos($frase, $minusculas[$j], $i);` means you're basically looping on the `$minusculas` array only, which is in alphabetical order.

Another error you have in your code is if your string contains repetitive letters like `hkgkh`, it  will only print GKH.

And a major issue you have in your code is the `return null` statement you have in the `for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud + 1; $i++) {` loop. This will only fun your loop for 1 iteration.

Comment: What im doing in that loop is verifying the position for the letter in the array, and if the function returns a true, is supossed to print the same position but in the $mayusculas array and i thought that the uppercase should be printed in te order that they're verified, do you suggest something??

Comment: I suggest you remove the `return null` and change `if($resultado !== FALSE){` to `if($resultado !== FALSE && $resultado == $i ){` and see the result.

Comment: Also change `strrpos` to `strpos`. And since this an exercise, I suggest you read the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if is unnecessary use the function `strpos` is:

In you PHP section:

```
$frase = $_POST['frase'];

function mayusculas($frase) {

$longitud = strlen($frase);
$minusculas = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","w","x","y","z"," ");
$mayusculas = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"," ");
$numeroLetras = count($minusculas);

for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < $numeroLetras ; $j++) {
        if($minusculas[$j] == $frase[$i]) {
            print($mayusculas[$j]);
        }
    }
  }

}

print(mayusculas($frase));
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know that you can go through an string like an array, its very helpful!